# Android AnimationDrawable starts, and when done hangs on first frame

Tags: android, animation, drawable, repeat

I'm trying to get the AnimationDrawable on my Android app to repeat.
I configured the android:oneshot on false. (tried both with java and with XML)
Still, whenever the animation is played, once it's done, it goes back to the first frame, and stops

This is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/network_scanning" android:oneshot="false">  
<item android:drawable="@drawable/network_wireless_0" android:duration="300" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/network_wireless_1" android:duration="300" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/network_wireless_2" android:duration="300" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/network_wireless_3" android:duration="300" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/network_wireless_4" android:duration="300" />
</animation-list>
```

and this is the code to start the animation:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
{
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    LinearLayout network = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.wifi_anim);
    AnimationDrawable anim = (AnimationDrawable) network.getBackground();
    if (hasFocus)
    {
        anim.setOneShot(false);
        anim.setCallback(network);
        anim.setVisible(true, true);
        anim.start();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

hi you can get solution from here

http://docs.mono-android.net/Android.Graphics.Drawables.AnimationDrawable